# Convert Rows to Column in SQL Server using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to pivot, I have a table like the below. It has Model Number and Group No details. The table contains 10 distinct groups.

[image]

I am trying to achieve the result set like this. Just want to list out all the Model under each group.

[image]

I tried with this SQL Query, but here I am partially getting the result. It display only one row.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ModelNo
        ,GroupNo
    FROM #Table
    ) d
pivot(max(ModelNo) FOR GroupNo IN (
            [1]
            ,[2]
            ,[3]
            ,[4]
            ,[5]
            ,[6]
            ,[7]
            ,[8]
            ,[9]
            ,[10]
            )) piv
```

I am not sure where am I missing. Kindly assist me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend conditional aggregation over `pivot` -- it is simply much more versatile.

What you need is `row_number()`, so the query looks like:

```
select max(case when groupno = 1 then modelno end) as group_01,
       max(case when groupno = 2 then modelno end) as group_02,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by groupno order by modelno) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

You can also incorporate this idea into a `pivot` as well.

Comment: I hope this approach will perform better with million records as well since I just given a sample data set. Thank you so much for the approach. When I try like this, the results are scattered across the group. Is any way I can display distinct ModelNos under each group.

Comment: @StackUser . . . I don't understand what you mean by "scattered across the group".  Perhaps you only need `order by seqnum`.  If that doesn't fix the issue, can you set up a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry @Gordon Linoff, Your SQL Query is fine. Its completely my mistake only. You are rocking.Thanks a ton. I selected your answer and up voted as well. I have struggled for the past 8 hours and hitting my heads to get this result.